# DocumentDB Emulator Crashes on Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, emulation, azure-cosmosdb

I am just getting started with DocumentDB/Cosmos and have ran into an error and I'm not sure if it my doing or a bug. For ease of testing I am using the DocumentDB emulator V1.13.58.2, and the C# DocumentDB SDK V1.14.0.

Everything works fine until I try to do a Linq query where I do an equality test on a document property other than id. It works if I use id otherwise the DocumentDB server crashes. I also tried downgrading to V1.13.4 of the SDK and it throws an exception "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: ≻. Path '', line 0, position 0".

Below is the code that I use to create the problem.

First I created a simple class to use which I then add some instances to the db. I can see the documents are successfully created with the correct partitions in the document explorer.

```
public class TestEntityClass
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "type")]
    public int DocumentType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "pId")]
    public string PartitionId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "stringProperty")]
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "numberProperty")]
    public int NumberProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then I try and query on the DB using linq where "match" is a Linq expression.

```
using (var query = m_Client.CreateDocumentQuery<TObject>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(m_DBName, m_ColName),
            new FeedOptions() { MaxItemCount = 1 }).Where(m => m.PartitionId == PartitionId && m.DocumentType == m_Type)
            .Where(match).AsDocumentQuery())
        {
            var response = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<TObject>();
            if (response.Count == 0) { return null; }
            return response.ElementAt(0);
        }
```

When I set match to

```
match = m => m.Id == entity1.Id;
```

it works fine.

However if I set match to

```
match = m => m.NumberProperty == entity1.NumberProperty;
```

or

```
match = m => m.StringProperty == entity1.StringProperty;
```

the DocumentDb server crashes.

Now all of this works fine on my cloud hosted Cosmos database so it is not a huge problem but I was just curious if it was something I was doing or just a bug. If anyone has any insight I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a console application and connect to Azure Cosmos DB Emulator instance, I could query and filter documents based on both id property and other properties.

*Class TestEntityClass (same as yours):*

```
public class TestEntityClass
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "type")]
    public int DocumentType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "pId")]
    public string PartitionId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "stringProperty")]
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "numberProperty")]
    public int NumberProperty { get; set; }
}
```

*packages.config*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB" version="1.14.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

[image]

*Note*: set `EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true` if execute a query across partitions

Please try to use `TestEntityClass` in `CreateDocumentQuery<TestEntityClass>` instead of `CreateDocumentQuery<TObject>`, and check if same error appear.

Comment: Hum, I tried this on a different computer and it worked fine for me as well. So I then tried to run my original code and it also worked on this computer. Something must be messed up with my environment on my other computer. Thanks for your time and help.